# Sort nested observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, angular2-nativescript

I have here a JSON file which looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "question": "What is your age range?",
        "options": ["10-20","20-30","30-40","40-50"]
    },
    {
        "question": "How did you find us?",
        "options": ["Friend recommendation","Google","Other"]
    },
    {
        "question": "Are you interested in etcetc?",
        "options": ["No","Yes","Meh"]
    }
]
```

In my project I've got a model with the same structure which looks like this:

```
export interface Test {
    question: string;
    options: string[];
}
```

in my service file, I read the file like so (turning it into an observable, because I want to be able to change the order of the data and possibly later add/remove/change questions):

```
getSurveyQuestion(): Observable<Test[]> {
    return this.http
        .get<Test[]>("/path/to/questions.json")
        .do(data => console.log("All : " + JSON.stringify(data)))
}
```

In the console, the above outputs:

> JS: All : [{"question":"What is your age range?,"options":["10-20","20-30","30-40","40-50"]}, { //.....}]

My component file looks as follows:

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    propertyData: Test[] = [];

    constructor(private router: Router, private testService: TestService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.testService.getSurveyQuestion().subscribe(data => {
            this.propertyData = data;
        }, err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
}
```

In my html, I output it to the screen like so:

```
<StackLayout *ngFor="let item of propertyData">
    <Label text="{{item.question}}"></label>
</StackLayout>
```

now, I want to add a button or something to the html, which on tap calls a function to rearrange the items the user can see on screen. For now, something that simply arranges the array of observables by question (alphabetically, ascending or descending) is good enough. I've been trying to accomplish this for hours, but nothing I found on google (and stackoverflow) has helped me accomplish this yet.

Does any of you know how to sort/rearrange the data of an observable in the way I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance.

(in case it helps, I'm working with NativeScript + Angular).

Comment: I assume that at some point you store the questions array in the propertyData property of the class. That is not shown in the code you pasted. If that is so just make some methods and use the Array.sort method to reorder the items. Then call those methods from the template.

Comment: Ah yes, apologies. I've updated the question. I've been trying to use the array.sort, but I must be using it wrong as I've never been able to reference the questions. I assumed I'd do it like `this.propertyData.question` but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Observable [`map`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) operator to sort the list.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.testService.getSurveyQuestion()
      .map(data => {
        return data.sort((a: Test, b: Test) => {
          const aQ = test.question.toUpperCase();
          const bQ = test.question.toUpperCase();
          return aQ.localeCompare(bQ); // that will sort them alphabetically
        )); 
      })
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.propertyData = data;
      });
  }
```

Now as for the question of changing the way they are sorted when you click a button, that's a bit trickier. You will want to make the function being used for sorting asynchronous. You could do that by making a property on your component:

```
sortFn$ = new BehaviorSubject<SortFnType>(alphabeticalSort // or whatever default sort you want);
```

Read more about `BehaviorSubject`s here: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject

Then `next` functions to that `BehaviorSubject` when the button is clicked.

```
onClick() {
  const reverseAlphabeticalSort = (a: Test, b: Test) => {
      const aQ = test.question.toUpperCase();
      const bQ = test.question.toUpperCase();
      return bQ.localeCompare(aQ); 
  });
  this.sortFn$.next(reverseAlphabeticalSort);
}
```

And then use [`combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest) to get it into your stream.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.testService.getSurveyQuestion()
    .combineLatest(this.sortFn$)
    .map(([data, sortFn]: [Test[], SortFnType]) => {
      return data.sort(sortFn);
    })
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.propertyData = data;
    });
}
```

Also, I'd recommend using the `async` pipe to pass your data into your template so you don't have to mess with Subscription cleanup.

```
<StackLayout *ngFor="let item of sortedData$ | async">
  <Label text="{{item.question}}"></label>
</StackLayout>
```

Then in your component:

```
sortedData$: Observable<Test[]>;

ngOnInit() {
   this.sortedData$ = this.testService.getSurveyQuestion()
    .combineLatest(this.sortFn$)
    .map(([data, sortFn]: [Test[], SortFnType]) => {
      return data.sort(sortFn);
    })
  }
```

Note that the code above is in "rough draft" form and will probably require some minor tweaks / edits to work in your program, but the approach there will work for your use case.

Comment: Let me know if this answered your question or if you need more information.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, I'm currently trying to implement it in my use case. It's tricky considering I'm new to a lot of stuff, and therefore taking very long to resolve certain things. For instance: I tried putting `sortFn$ = new BehaviorSubject<SortFnType>(alphabeticalSort)` gives me an error for `<SortFnType>`: (Cannot find name 'SortFnType') and `alphabeticalSort`: (Cannot find name 'alphabeticalSort'). It's probably because I'm missing something, but stuff like that just takes ages for me to figure out haha :)

Comment: Well, you'll need to implement 'alphabeticalSort' yourself, as well as define `SortFnType` yourself. `alphabeticalSort` will be very similar to `reverseAlphabeticalSort` shown in my answer -- I"ll leave it to you to get that one working :). `SortFnType` is just a placeholder I made up for a Typescript type. I'd recommend reading about Typescript custom types. For now, just replace `SortFnType` with `any` and worry about it later.

Comment: Ahh, ok I see. I'll play around with this for a bit. I'll accept your answer because it certainly pointed me in a direction I never would've figured out myself. Should I still not get it after hours of banging my head against this, I can always open up a new question. Thank you very much for your time! :)

Comment: Happy to help :) -- don't be too hard on yourself. Have patience, you'll get it eventually if you keep working at it. You're on the right track! Feel free to look me up on my profile and contact me with future questions.