# Async Pipe not showing data from observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, angular2-nativescript

Yesterday, I asked a question about [sorting nested observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48490703/sort-nested-observable). Shortly after, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48491243/1853248) pointed me in a good general direction. I managed to "correctly" incorporate the code into my own project - that is to say, TypeScript is not giving me any errors. Please refer to the below codesnippets:

**survery.json**

```
[
    {
        "question": "What is your age range?",
        "options": ["10-20","20-30","30-40","40-50"]
    },
    {
        "question": "How did you find us?",
        "options": ["Friend recommendation","Google","Other"]
    },
    {
        "question": "Are you interested in etcetc?",
        "options": ["No","Yes","Meh"]
    }
]
```

**test.model.ts**

```
export interface Test {
    question: string;
    options: string[];
}
```

**test.service.ts**

```
export class TestService {        
    constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 

    }

    getSurveyQuestion(): Observable<Test[]> {
        return this.http
            .get<Test[]>("/path/to/questions.json")
            .do(data => console.log("All : " + JSON.stringify(data)))

    }
}
```

**test.component.ts**

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    propertyData : Test[] = [];
    sortedData$: Observable<Test[]>;
    sortFn$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.alphabeticalSort);

    constructor(private router: Router, private testService: TestService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sortedData$ = this.testService.getSurveyQuestion()
            .combineLatest(this.sortFn$)
            .map(([data, sortFn]: [Test[], any]) => {
                return data.sort(sortFn);
            });
    }

    alphabeticalSort() {
        const sortAlphabetAsc = (a: Test, b: Test) => {
            const aQ = a.question.toUpperCase();
            const bQ = b.question.toUpperCase();
            return aQ.localeCompare(bQ);
        };
        this.sortFn$.next(sortAlphabetAsc);
    }
}
```

**test.component.html**

```
<Label [text]="'Sort by alphabetical order'"(tap)="alphabeticalSort()"></Label>
StackLayout *ngFor="let item of sortedData$ | async">
    <Label text="{{item.question}}"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Now, the problem is that my app does not show any data. Only the button (Label) is there. My question is, where am I going wrong? the `console.log` in **test.service.ts** does output the data correctly:

> JS: All : [{"question":"What is your age range?,"options":["10-20","20-30","30-40","40-50"]}, { //.....}]

Perhaps it's also worth mentioning that, every time I boot up the app with my debugger (I use visual studio code), the emulator crashes. This seems to be a problem with my async pipe, because if I remove `| async` from the html code, it loads up fine (obviously without any data being displayed on my screen).

I'm guessing this is because somewhere I'm trying to fetch too much (infinite?) data, but I really don't know. If I then, later, re-add the async pipe and save the file, the debugger reloads the app and that does *not* crash.

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem but what you are doing with `alphabeticalSort` is a bit strange. Why not just reference your sort function in your `map` operator? Why use `combineLatest`?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here: `sortFn$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.alphabeticalSort);`. You are passing a reference to a function (which I think will lose the scope of `this`). Then in the map you are using it like it is the sorting function but it is just the function that causes the sorting function to emit for `sortFn$`.

Comment: @bygrace basically, for now, I've got a list of questions in my html file. By default, I want it to be sorted in the way you retrieve them from the JSON file (so that'd be in the order they're inside the JSON file). Then, if you tap a label which calls the `alphabeticalSort()` method, I want it to order the questions in this list in an alphabetical order. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on what exactly is broken but there are some yellow/red flags around the `sortFn$`. You shouldn't be passing a function reference to it as its initial value. I think that you can simplify the code by doing the following:

- Setup the sorting method as a class method rather than generating it and passing it through an observable stream.
- Trigger sorting with a boolean stream (default to false). Reference the subject in the view and call next on tap.

Might look something like this:

**test.component.ts**

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    propertyData : Test[] = [];
    sortedData$: Observable<Test[]>;
    sort$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    constructor(private router: Router, private testService: TestService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sortedData$ = this.testService.getSurveyQuestion()
            .combineLatest(this.sort$)
            .map(([data, sort]: [Test[], boolean]) => {
                return sort ? data.sort(this.alphabeticalSort) : data;
            });
    }

    alphabeticalSort(a: Test, b: Test) {
        const aQ = a.question.toUpperCase();
        const bQ = b.question.toUpperCase();
        return aQ.localeCompare(bQ);
    }
}
```

**test.component.html**

```
<Label [text]="'Sort by alphabetical order'"(tap)="sort$.next(true)"></Label>
StackLayout *ngFor="let item of sortedData$ | async">
    <Label text="{{item.question}}"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```